# Liquibase: Do I really need to add a rollback section for one-row insert?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Assume, that we have the following changeset:

```
   <changeSet id="add_ACME_code_to_tbl_acme" author="developer">
        <sql>
            INSERT INTO tbl_acme(identifier, description, code)
            VALUES (nextval('seq_acme'), 'acme description', 'ACME');
        </sql>
        <rollback>
            <delete tableName="tbl_acme">
                <where>code = 'ACME'</where>
            </delete>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
```

where I am just trying to insert one row to the table.

The discussion that was started during the code review:

Do we really need to have a rollback section for a simple one-row insert and what exactly we need to do here? (in the case when insert failed, does it make any sense try to remove something that we tried to insert without success?) and what exactly can go wrong with an insert?

Comment: The `rollback` isn't for the error handling (as that is done by the transaction running the insert), but if you want to rollback an already deployed change

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, do you want to say, that liquibase will not execute the rollback that I specified automatically in a case when changeset failed?

Comment: Correct. By default, Liquibase will run a changeset in a transaction, and thus when an error happens, everything will be rolled back. The `<rollback>` servers a completely different purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Liquibase rollbacks are a bit confusing. They are designed to roll **already executed changeSets** back.

Check out this article about [Rollling back changes](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-rollback.html)

> “Roll Back To” Modes
>
> You can specify what changes to rollback in three ways:
>
> **Tag**
>
> Specifying a tag to rollback to will roll back all change-sets that
> were executed against the target database after the given tag was
> applied. See the command line documentation for how to tag your
> database.

E.g. `iquibase:rollback -Dliquibase.rollbackTag=your-database-tag` - It'll rollback all the changeSets after the `your-database-tag` was created. (you can create a tag via `liquibase tag` command).

> **Number of Change Sets**
>
> You can specify the number of change-sets to rollback.

E.g. `liquibase:rollbackCountSQL 5` - It'll rollback the last 5 executed changeSets.

> **Date**
>
> You can specify the date to roll back to.

E.g. `liquibase rollbackToDate 2020-05-01T08:36:17` - It'll roll back all the changeSets which were executed after the provided date.

By the way, it's not always necessary to write rollback statements. Most of the time Liquibase generates rollback statements itself. For example, the generated rollback statement for `<createTable tableName="new_table">` will be:

```
<rollback>
    <dropTable tableName="new_table"/>
</rollback>
```

But if you want to override it, you can always create your own `<rollback>`.

---

About failed changeSets:

Liquibase executes the changeSets in transaction. And if the changeSet fails, then the transaction's rollback it invoked and no changes will be made.

`<rollback>` has nothing to do with error handling.